# Opening a file on a shared drive blocks access to other users

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I access a lot of shared files on a Windows-based networked drive (CIFS) for work. There is an annoying issue that effects other people only when when I'm accessing a file from my Ubuntu machine.

Here is the usual scenario where nothing bad happens:

> 1. Windows/Mac User #1 opens a file on the network drive
> 2. User #2 (any OS) tries to open that same file while User #1 still
>      has it open.
> 3. User #2 see a popup that says the file is in use, but user #2 will be  given an option to open a read-only copy.

However, if the *Ubuntu* user opens the file first, something different happens. Here is the scenario where the failure happens:

> 1. Ubuntu User #1 opens a file on the network drive
> 2. User #2 (any OS) tries to open that same file while Ubuntu User #1
>      still has it open
> 3. User #2 will get an error saying "the file is in use" and is NOT
>      given the option to open a read-only copy.

Is there anyway to modify my settings to allow other users to view a read-only copy of a shared file while I am accessing it from Ubuntu?

Comment: Just to be sure: the ubuntu user opens the file via a 'windows network' connection?